# 'Azure Search Notification -Error detecting index schema from data source'

Tags: azure

Yesterday I could easily import data from blobstorage to my Azure Search Index. Today I get an error message all the time when I try to import the data. The service tries to sample the data source and ends up with an error message. The error message is

'Azure Search Notification -Error detecting index schema from data source'

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue that we are in the process of fixing. The deployments are being rolled out by region and should be completed within the next couple of days.

Comment: What do you mean by "we"? Are you trying to say you have some involvement with fixing this problem in Azure? Please be specific.

Comment: Yes, I'm on the Azure Search team.

Comment: Do you plan to make any public announcement, e.g. on Azure status? Or is there already something public that you can link to?